# How to get the sum of the column in Crystal Reports?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, crystal-reports

How to get the sum of the particular column value in [Crystal Reports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_Reports)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to right click on your number field and choose Insert/Summary. Within the Insert Summary window you have the options to choose the field to summarize, how to calculate the summary, and which section to put the summary.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Sum()` function of Crystal Reports.