# Sum of particular column in crystal Report

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to **sum** the column (i.e, price) in **Crystal Report**. I am using VS2012.
How to do that?
Please reply using images to make it understand better.

Comment: Please First Search before create your question .  
Link for same Question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891153/how-to-get-the-sum-of-the-column-in-crystal-reports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to

- Right click on your number field and choose Insert/Summary.
- Within the Insert Summary window you have the options to choose the
  field to summarize, how to calculate the summary, and which section
  to put the summary.

Comment: I want to sum the Price column. But in "Calculate summary" dropdown i cant see the "Sum" field. Please reply

Comment: That Columns Should be Numeric value like (int,float) then only you can see there

Answer (score 0):

use `sum(YourcolumnName)` in expression.

Comment: Please explain with the help of images. Also, I had used the same but its giving error "A number field or currency amount field is required here"
How to solve?

Comment: look at http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/Chapter06_XI.asp for conversion